# Formula to check if month and year within range

Tags: date, range, excel-formula

I am after a formula where it returns a 1 or a 0 depending on whether the month and year is in the range of two cells.

For example:

If you look at the below table, if Column D is Jan-12, I need the Test1 row for it to show as 0 as it the month and year in that Jan-12 cell is not within the range of Column B and C for Test 1. I need to do this formula across many rows and columns so any easy to maintain formula would be ideal :)

```
Column A     Column B     Column C     Column D      Column E     Column F   ............
Title        Start Date   End Date       Jan-12      Feb-12        Mar-12 ............
__________________________________________________________________________________

Test1        17-Sep-12    10-Dec-13       0             0            0
Test2        14-Jan-12    16-Mar-13       1             1            1
Test3        12-Mar-12    28-Mar-12       0             0            1
```

Comment: Just updated, let me know if you can see it :)

Comment: Please be more specific about the context. Are you writing code in a specific language? Working in a tool like Excel? Other? Also consider tagging the question with the appropriate language/tool/platform.

Comment: Just a simple formula in Excel. I want to enter it in to a Excel Cell so it returns a 0 or 1 if the condition is true or not.

Comment: OK I see what you mean now and can see the table

Comment: Thanks. Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: @JosephJaajaa let me know if the formula worked

Answer (score 0):

This is the formula you need:

For Test1 assuming columns D, E, F are on row 1:

D:

```
=IF(AND(D1>$B$2,D1<$C$2),1,0)
```

E:

```
=IF(AND(E1>$B$2,E1<$C$2),1,0)
```

F:

```
=IF(AND(F1>$B$2,F1<$C$2),1,0)
```

Apply same concept for other columns. Checkout the example I put together and let me know if this helped [Zoho Docs](https://docs.zoho.com/sheet/published.do?rid=gu1wa1add943c536c4f48ac72dd4be41d1044)

Comment: @JosephJaajaa can you acknowledge the answer

Comment: This won't work for dates that equal the first date. Also, the formula as listed has to manually changed for each column. My answer will correct those items.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest some editing of Chelseawillrecover's method so that the formula can be dragged to the entire desired range, without manipulation in each cell. Easier to update later if needed, and easier to add now as it looks like you have many columns to update (and probably a lot of rows). Also a change to the formula to check to see if the date is greater than or equal to the first date and less than the second date.

in Cell D2 enter:

```
=IF(AND(D$1>=$B2,D$1<$C2),1,0)
```